# Calculate number of tickets by client

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a beginner with R.

I have a df with 3 columns : `IDTICKET`, `IDCLIENT` and `TIC_TOTAL_TCC`

I want to calculate the number of tickets that have `TIC_TOTAL_TCC < 0` by client.

I begin with something like that:

```
nb_ticket_remb <- merge_all2 %>%
  group_by(IDCLIENT,IDTICKET) %>%
  summarise(RemboursementTicket = sum(TIC_TOTALTTC[TIC_TOTALTTC] < 0))
```

But it's not the good result.
How can I do this with `dplyr`?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Which is it ">" or "<"? And why wouldn't the expression on left side of the inequality be just `TIC_TOTALTTC`?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood your question, but this might help:

```
IDCLIENT <- rep(sample(1:5), 3)
IDTICKET <- rep(sample(1:5), 3)
TIC_TOTAL_TCC <- rep(sample(1:5), 3)
library(dplyr)
tibble(IDCLIENT, IDTICKET, TIC_TOTAL_TCC) %>%
  group_by(IDCLIENT) %>%
  filter(TIC_TOTAL_TCC < 0) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

The function `n`, used above returns the number of rows of the original data set that have `TIC_TOTAL_TCC < 0` for each value of `IDCLIENT`. Is that what you seek?

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulties because one of your errors was a misspelling htat I didn't recognize: `TIC_TOTAL_TCC != TIC_TOTAL_TTC`. If you filter first you can use `n()` to get your tallies:

```
set.seed(123)
IDCLIENT <- sample(1:5, 33,repl=TRUE)
IDTICKET <- sample(1:5, 33,repl=TRUE)
TIC_TOTAL_TCC <- sample( (-2):5, 33, repl=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
merge_all2 <- tibble(IDCLIENT, IDTICKET, TIC_TOTAL_TCC)
merge_all2 %>% filter( TIC_TOTAL_TCC < 0) %>%  
               group_by(IDCLIENT) %>% 
                summarise( n=n() )
```

And once I corrected the spelling error (and the error of indexing a value by itself) your code worked as well:

```
merge_all2 %>%
   group_by(IDCLIENT) %>% summarise(RemboursementTicket = sum(TIC_TOTAL_TCC < 0))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  IDCLIENT RemboursementTicket
     <int>               <int>
1        1                   2
2        2                   1
3        3                   2
4        4                   1
5        5                   3
```